# fixture_file_upload & Rack::Test::UploadedFile - ActiveStorage::IntegrityError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, minitest, rails-activestorage

Here's a fun ActiveStorage issue which has been causing me to scratch my head in confusion for a couple of days; ActiveStorage seems to not be playing well with either `fixture_file_upload` & `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` as both methods are throwing the following error when saving a file to a model attachment using ActiveStorage:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.4)
irb(main):001:0> Attachment.create({file: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/tracer1.jpg", 'tracer1.jpg')})
D, [2021-01-22T16:20:03.695894 #498] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
D, [2021-01-22T16:20:03.730325 #498] DEBUG -- :   Attachment Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "attachments" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-01-22 16:20:03.726078"], ["updated_at", "2021-01-22 16:20:03.726078"]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:20:03.735233 #498] DEBUG -- :   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 1], ["record_type", "Attachment"], ["name", "file"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:20:03.736695 #498] DEBUG -- :   ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "uk44hg6aeqgkijnoti7625kmymn5"], ["filename", "tracer1.jpg"], ["content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 71843], ["checksum", "fleS+FPvNcLEHaUysUgaGQ=="], ["created_at", "2021-01-22 16:20:03.735850"]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:20:03.737593 #498] DEBUG -- :   ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "file"], ["record_type", "Attachment"], ["record_id", 1], ["blob_id", 4], ["created_at", "2021-01-22 16:20:03.736870"]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:20:03.739022 #498] DEBUG -- :   Attachment Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "attachments" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "attachments"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2021-01-22 16:20:03.737884"], ["id", 1]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:20:03.740233 #498] DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  COMMIT
I, [2021-01-22T16:20:03.740753 #498]  INFO -- :   Disk Storage (0.0ms) Deleted file from key: uk44hg6aeqgkijnoti7625kmymn5
I, [2021-01-22T16:20:03.740868 #498]  INFO -- :   Disk Storage (0.5ms) Uploaded file to key: uk44hg6aeqgkijnoti7625kmymn5 (checksum: fleS+FPvNcLEHaUysUgaGQ==)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
ActiveStorage::IntegrityError (ActiveStorage::IntegrityError)
```

This issue, however, isn't seen when using the following method of attaching a file.

```
irb(main):001:0> attachment = Attachment.new
=> #<Attachment id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, parent_type: nil, parent_id: nil, frame: "{}", user_id: nil>
irb(main):002:0> attachment.file.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root + 'test/fixtures/files/tracer1.jpg'), filename: 'tracer1.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg')
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Changes::CreateOne:0x0000563b16d6bdc8 @name="file", @record=#<Attachment id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, parent_type: nil, parent_id: nil, frame: "{}", user_id: nil>, @attachable={:io=>#<File:/app/test/fixtures/files/tracer1.jpg>, :filename=>"tracer1.jpg", :content_type=>"image/jpg"}>
irb(main):003:0> attachment.save
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.564371 #516] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.610210 #516] DEBUG -- :   Attachment Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "attachments" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-01-22 16:21:55.605710"], ["updated_at", "2021-01-22 16:21:55.605710"]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.615088 #516] DEBUG -- :   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 2], ["record_type", "Attachment"], ["name", "file"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.617341 #516] DEBUG -- :   ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "hjmhqkujbe2uxk6f9jfgmq5j4nn7"], ["filename", "tracer1.jpg"], ["content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 71843], ["checksum", "fleS+FPvNcLEHaUysUgaGQ=="], ["created_at", "2021-01-22 16:21:55.615787"]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.618972 #516] DEBUG -- :   ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "file"], ["record_type", "Attachment"], ["record_id", 2], ["blob_id", 5], ["created_at", "2021-01-22 16:21:55.617781"]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.621752 #516] DEBUG -- :   Attachment Update (0.5ms)  UPDATE "attachments" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "attachments"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2021-01-22 16:21:55.619356"], ["id", 2]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.627906 #516] DEBUG -- :    (6.0ms)  COMMIT
I, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.628651 #516]  INFO -- :   Disk Storage (0.4ms) Uploaded file to key: hjmhqkujbe2uxk6f9jfgmq5j4nn7 (checksum: fleS+FPvNcLEHaUysUgaGQ==)
I, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.632122 #516]  INFO -- : Enqueued ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 5e869e72-e190-4a73-8938-14db177822a0) to Async(active_storage_analysis) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x0000563b18c40938 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://cosplay/ActiveStorage::Blob/5>>
=> true
irb(main):004:0> D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.691199 #516] DEBUG -- :   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
I, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.691873 #516]  INFO -- : Performing ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 5e869e72-e190-4a73-8938-14db177822a0) from Async(active_storage_analysis) enqueued at 2021-01-22T16:21:55Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x0000563b1947abf8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://cosplay/ActiveStorage::Blob/5>>
I, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.797208 #516]  INFO -- :   Disk Storage (0.1ms) Downloaded file from key: hjmhqkujbe2uxk6f9jfgmq5j4nn7
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.845133 #516] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  BEGIN
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.845853 #516] DEBUG -- :   ActiveStorage::Blob Update (0.5ms)  UPDATE "active_storage_blobs" SET "metadata" = $1 WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $2  [["metadata", "{\"identified\":true,\"width\":575,\"height\":862,\"analyzed\":true}"], ["id", 5]]
D, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.847209 #516] DEBUG -- :    (0.9ms)  COMMIT
I, [2021-01-22T16:21:55.847513 #516]  INFO -- : Performed ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 5e869e72-e190-4a73-8938-14db177822a0) from Async(active_storage_analysis) in 155.55ms
```

Here's the model used in the above 2 examples.

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I really appreciate any help or insight anyone out there has on this issue; I essentially have a very large test suite which uses `fixture_file_upload` & `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` pretty much everywhere as they are very useful, however, as you can see they are not working anymore in combination with ActiveStorage.

Here are my [Gemfile & Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/shawndeprey/9dd2b93ad4e76e28158cc2810dff2b39) if it helps debug what's going on; I've also included a minitest test file on that gist which has 2 failing and 1 succeeding test. I am happy to provide any additional details if it helps debug the issue.

Additional details which could be helpful:

Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61

docker-compose version 1.25.5, build unknown

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, I know it's not the best solution, but it may work for you:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    full_name { FFaker::NameBR.name }
    email     { FFaker::Internet.unique.email }

    trait :with_avatar_image do
      after(:build) do |user|
        user.avatar_image.attach(io: File.open('public/examples/my_image.jpg'), filename: 'my_image.jpg')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So create this way:

```rb
let!(:user) { create(:user, :with_avatar_image) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; this is also what I did in the short term to overcome the issue in some of my test cases. Unfortunately this basically this just avoids the issue. Additionally, I believe the attributes_for method will not include the attachment in the produced object in this configuration in my testing, meaning using the factory in functional tests setups will be a bit bothersome.

I still haven't figured out any other solution from my end either but will certainly update on this thread if I figure something out.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, with params like this works:

```rb
Attachment.create(file: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'test.jpg'), 'image/jpg'))
```

For tests, you may try this:

```rb
# Step 1, test_helper.rb
FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner.class_eval do
  # If you want to use `fixture_file_upload` with Rails 6.0
  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess 
  
  # You may need this to use `fixture_file_upload` with Rails 6.1
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::FileFixtures 
end

# Step 2, attachments.rb
factory :attachment do
  name { 'name' }

  # As a must have attribute  
  file {
    fixture_file_upload( 
      Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'test.jpg'), 'image/jpg')
  }

  # As an optional attribute
  trait :with_file do
    file {
      fixture_file_upload(
        Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'test.jpg'), 'image/jpg')
    }
  end
end
# You could replace `fixture_file_upload` with `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new`

# Step 3, now you can use:
# As a must have attribute
attachment1 = create(:attachment)
attributes1 = attributes_for(:attachment)

# As an optional attribute
attachment2 = create(:attachment, :with_file)
attributes2 = attributes_for(:attachment, :with_file)
```